# I have tried altering this code many times it just doesnt work

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried this vba code but it just isnt working i am not able to see the error.This is the code

```
Sub RetrieveData()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetFilePath As String
    Dim targetFileName As String
    
    ' Set the target file path and name
    targetFilePath = "\\kcjmserver\E\Data\Overseas Projects\Honilac Nutrition Limited\2023\Amazon reconciliation\D05 May 2023\Vlookup"
    targetFileName = "InventoryItems-20230605.xlsx"
    
    ' Open the target workbook
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(targetFilePath & "\" & targetFileName)
    
    ' Set the target worksheet
    Set targetWorksheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Replace "Sheet1" with the actual sheet name
    
    ' Loop through the data in Sheet1
    For i = 2 To 26
        ' Perform the VLOOKUP
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 10).Value = Application.VLookup(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Value, targetWorksheet.Range("A:M"), 9, False)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value = Application.VLookup(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Value, targetWorksheet.Range("A:M"), 3, False)
    Next i
    
    ' Close the target workbook
    targetWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
    ' Release the memory
    Set targetWorksheet = Nothing
    Set targetWorkbook = Nothing
End Sub
```

I have tried alternate codes nothing seems to work i want to fetch data from another workbook

Comment: The syntax looks good, but before I try any fix, I need you to confirm that your target paths are all accessible. Does the machine that need to execute your code have permission to use the documents as well? Please also double check the sheet name is indeed "Sheet1". If you have renamed it, or your national default isn't english you could get an error. If none of these things are the issue, all I can think of is the datatype. Are they consistent between the lookup sheet and the target sheet?

Comment: First what I did is that from the target workbook, I copied the data to the current sheet and it worked .basically when I used the lookup function in a single worksheet and not from another workbook it worked.

Comment: Sub RetrieveData()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To 26
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 10).Value = Application.VLookup(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Value, Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B:M"), 9, False)
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 7).Value = Application.VLookup(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 6).Value, Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("B:M"), 3, False)
    Next i
End Sub

This was the successful code that ran

Comment: \\kcjmserver\E\Data\Overseas Projects\Honilac Nutrition Limited\2023\Amazon reconciliation\D05 May 2023\Vlookup\InventoryItems-20230605.xlsx-This is my path
InventoryItems-20230605-This is the file name

Comment: So you had a previous code that worked fine, but you're trying to write a better code that now doesn't work, is that right? In the original code, I notice you making a lookup in a sheet called "Sheet3" which you do not use in your new code. Could this be our faulty cog? Please confirm once more all the sheet references.

Comment: Yes in the original code, I just copied the data from InventoryItems-20230605 in the Current sheet just to make my code simplified and make the VBA code work in the same sheet and it worked therefore I tried to make it better and get the data altogether from a different workbook,

Comment: My doubt in the code is  in the file path it is fetching "\\kcjmserver\E\Data\Overseas Projects\Honilac Nutrition Limited\2023\Amazon reconciliation\D05 May 2023\Vlookup"
whereas if i copy my path from File-Copy path my path comes as \\kcjmserver\E\Data\Overseas Projects\Honilac Nutrition Limited\2023\Amazon reconciliation\D05 May 2023\Vlookup\InventoryItems-20230605.xlsx Do u think that makes the difference

Comment: `Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 10).Value =` is that sheet1 in the workbook that the macro is in ?

Comment: Yes the lookup values are in Columns 10 and 7 and value against which it is being looked up is in column 6

Answer (score 1):

Add `ThisWorkbook` to references to `Worksheets("Sheet1")`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub RetrieveData()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim wbLookUp As Workbook, rngLookUp As Range
    
    ' Set the look-up file path and name
    Const LookUpPath = "\\kcjmserver\E\Data\Overseas Projects\Honilac Nutrition Limited\2023\Amazon reconciliation\D05 May 2023\Vlookup"
    Const LookUpName = "InventoryItems-20230605.xlsx"
    
    ' Open the look-up workbook
    Set wbLookUp = Workbooks.Open(LookUpPath & "\" & LookUpName)
    
    ' Set the look-up range
    With wbLookUp
        Set rngLookUp = .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:M")
    End With
    
    ' Loop through the data in Sheet1
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 2 To 26
            ' Perform the VLOOKUP
            .Cells(i, 7).Value = Application.VLookup(.Cells(i, 6).Value, rngLookUp, 3, False)
            .Cells(i, 10).Value = Application.VLookup(.Cells(i, 6).Value, rngLookUp, 9, False)
        Next i
    End With
    
    ' Close the look-up workbook
    wbLookUp.Close SaveChanges:=False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please let me know what change does it make .I just want to know for knowledge purpose

Comment: @Yash If you don't qualify worksheets with a specific workbook then the default value may not be the one intended.